# What is required to differentiate magnetic north from south?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Assuming I simply have some random magnets laying around, I don't believe it's possible to differentiate north from south (if I'm wrong, then my question becomes "why?"). I think I could apply an arbitrary designation to each of the poles, and then use that first arbitrarily labelled magnet to label the rest. I'd get it right 50% of the time.

What additional, minimal items would be required to determine which pole was north or south? The answer should be able to yield magnets who's labeling matches magnets on Earth. Assume that an outside magnetic field is weak or unknown (or you're not on Earth).

I guess it might be possible to use a length of wire and an ammeter to measure current direction, but that may not be the easiest manner.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an ammeter. If you have a battery and a piece of copper wire, you can hook them up, and you know that current is flowing from $+$ to $-$ on the battery. Then you can determine which way the magnet wants to align based on the field generated by the current in the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Suspend a bar magnet from a string and allow it to align with the Earth's magnetic field. The end of the magnet pointing toward the geographic north is labeled North and the other end South.

Comment: There are no external magnetic fields available or they are unknown (i.e. you don't know north from south or aren't on Earth).

Answer (score 0):

The additional apparatus could be the Earth itself and a bowl of water on which floats a cork raft that can support one of the magnets without sinking. Then (assuming you aren't in the Arctic or Antarctic) the pole of the magnet that settles down to point (roughly) geographically North is, by definition, the magnet's North-seeking (or North) pole.

Comment: No Earth, no magnetic field.

Comment: If that restriction was in the original question, I apologise for this answer.

Comment: It wasn't very clear, so I'll forgive you :)